# Thunderbird: Type normal text after inserting a hyperlink

Tags: thunderbird

When composing an email in thunderbird, I will often type a phrase, select it, and turn it into a link using Ctrl+L. I then continue typing the email, but any text I insert after that link *also* becomes part of the link. How do I prevent this?

If I hit the return key, the link closes and a new line begins. But I don't want a line break. The only hack I know of is to type the rest of the line on a new line, and then delete the line break when I'm done.

Example of the problem (I don't want the text in parenthesis to be a part of the link):
[image: How to close this link?]
If you try to remove the link from just a portion of an existing hyperlink, the entire hyperlink is removed instead:

[image]

Comment: My setup is Ubuntu 16 & Thunderbird 45.8.0 ... If I hit the return key, the link CONTINUES on a new line also.

Answer (score 7):

> **Update:** Seems like Thunderbird changed the keyboard shortcut from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

When you need to add a link, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> insert the link and then continue typing. By pressing the keyboard shortcut a popup window will appear asking for the Description `Link Text` and the `Link Location`

[image: Thunderbird Link]

After you enter your link all you need to do is continue typing. The popup window will automatically cut off the link at the text you have specified.

Answer (score 7):

I just had the same problem and found that you can discontinue the link
with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: ctrl+shift+K is "format->discontinue link". This also didn't work for me, but typing a space did. I wonder if "format->discontinue style" is needed instead (ctrl+shift+Y).

Comment: Works now on latest version of thunderbird v60.8.0.